# Write javascript function tail

Tags: javascript

Write a JavaScript function, tail(anArray, num) that takes 2 arguments, an array and a number. Assume the number is an integer 0 or greater. tail should return a new array containing the first n elements of the input array. The elements should be in the reverse order as in the input array.

Comment: What's your question? What problems are you having with it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  This site is not a code writing service.  You will need to show some effort on your part in order for someone to help you.  Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Greetings! What have you tried yourself so far?

Answer (score 0):

`array.prototype.splice` can be used to get sub-arrays ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)). `array.prototype.reverse` can be used to reverse arrays ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)).

```js
let reverse = (arr, n) => {
  arr.splice(n);
  return arr.reverse();
};

let x = reverse([1, 2, 3, 4, 4], 3);

console.log(x);
```